# How to avoid polluting directory with CMake target logs

Tags: cmake

I have a simple project with one shared library called A and one executable called B linking A. I make a Visual Studio 2017 build just outside my sources so that the build directory and the source directory have both the same parent directory. This is fine.

But when I build my Visual Studio 2017 solution, many undesired directories appear under parent directory as well; one for each target that did run (A, B, INSTALL, etc.) that contains the build log for that target. I don't want those polluting log directories or it would be OK if they would appear under my build directory along Visual Studio 2017 stuff if they can't be avoided. Anyone knows how to handle this?

CMake version: 3.8.1

**EDIT**

The last 3 directories are those that are unwanted:

```
Parent directory
|-- build-vc15-x64 directory
    |-- VS 2017 related stuff
|-- sources directory
    |-- CMakeLists.txt
    |-- libA sources directory
        |-- stuff for libA
    |-- execB sources directory
        |-- stuff for execB
|-- unexpected directory here when building libA in solution in build-vc15-x64 (contains build log file of libA)
|-- unexpected directory here when building execB in solution in build-vc-15-x64 (contains build log file of execB)
|-- x64 (contains build log file of target INSTALL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use out-of-source builds, in other words, your build and your source directory should be different directories. Additionally, you have to call CMake and build just within your build directory, not in the parent directory. CMake creates a bunch of auxiliary files and directory right where it is called.

There is no point calling CMake in the common parent directory of source and build dir.

Comment: They are in different directories.

Comment: I have edited my question with schema. You will understand better what happens.